# FirebaseDatabase | No setter/field for xxx found on class | Firebase release apk doesn't load data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am an android developer, I used Firebase database for my app.
I run the app with app_debug.apk it works fine, but app_release.apk doesn't, it can't load Firebase database.
I checked the log file and I got this:

```
    No setter/field for xxx found on class
    [ex: xxx is a field in Post model]
```

I checked this post before: [No setter/field for xxx found on class link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192390/firebase-classmaper-no-setter-field-found-for-usertwo-on-class-myclass) and [release apk doesn't load data link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38587459/firebase-release-apk-not-loading-data)
,but they don't help me.
This is my model class:

```
abstract public class BaseModel {
public String userPhotoUrl= "";
public String contentPhotoUrl = "";
public BaseModel(){}

public BaseModel(String userPhotoUrl, String contentPhotoUrl) {
    this.userPhotoUrl = userPhotoUrl;
    this.contentPhotoUrl = contentPhotoUrl;
}

public String getUserPhotoUrl() {
    return userPhotoUrl;
}

public void setUserPhotoUrl(String userPhotoUrl) {
    this.userPhotoUrl = userPhotoUrl;
}

public String getContentPhotoUrl() {
    return contentPhotoUrl;
}

public void setContentPhotoUrl(String contentPhotoUrl) {
    this.contentPhotoUrl = contentPhotoUrl;
}
```

}

and

```
public class Post extends BaseModel{
protected String id ="";
protected String userId ="";
protected String userName = "";
protected String content = "";
protected int likeCount = 0;
protected int commentCount = 0;
protected long dataInverse = 0L; /*Use to sort data base publish experience*/
protected long sharedDate = 0L; /*TimeStamp in minisecond - The date expert shared.*/
protected String sharedSourceFrom = ""; /*From facebook or app*/
protected String facebookPostUrl = "";
public Post(){}

public Post(String id, String userId, String userName, String userPhotoUrl, String content, String contentPhotoUrl, int likeCount, int commentCount, long sharedDate, String sharedSourceFrom) {
    super(userPhotoUrl, contentPhotoUrl);
    this.id = id;
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.userPhotoUrl = userPhotoUrl;
    this.content = content;
    this.contentPhotoUrl = contentPhotoUrl;
    this.likeCount = likeCount;
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
    this.dataInverse = 0 - sharedDate;
    this.sharedDate = sharedDate;
    this.sharedSourceFrom = sharedSourceFrom;
    this.facebookPostUrl = "";
}
public String getUserPhotoUrl() {
    return userPhotoUrl;
}

public void setUserPhotoUrl(String userPhotoUrl) {
    this.userPhotoUrl = userPhotoUrl;
}

public String getContentPhotoUrl() {
    return contentPhotoUrl;
}

public void setContentPhotoUrl(String contentPhotoUrl) {
    this.contentPhotoUrl = contentPhotoUrl;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public int getLikeCount() {
    return likeCount;
}

public void setLikeCount(int likeCount) {
    this.likeCount = likeCount;
}

public int getCommentCount() {
    return commentCount;
}

public void setCommentCount(int commentCount) {
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
}

public long getDataInverse() {
    return dataInverse;
}

public void setDataInverse(long dataInverse) {
    this.dataInverse = dataInverse;
}

public long getSharedDate() {
    return sharedDate;
}

public void setSharedDate(long sharedDate) {
    this.sharedDate = sharedDate;
}

public String getSharedSourceFrom() {
    return sharedSourceFrom;
}

public void setSharedSourceFrom(String sharedSourceFrom) {
    this.sharedSourceFrom = sharedSourceFrom;
}

public String getFacebookPostUrl() {
    return facebookPostUrl;
}

public void setFacebookPostUrl(String facebookPostUrl) {
    this.facebookPostUrl = facebookPostUrl;
}
```

}

This is a datasnapshoot in Firebase database[image]

Do you have any suggestion to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Put a `@Keep` annotation on your `Post` class (and possibly also on your `BaseModel`). Also see my answer from yesterday here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010923/firebase-writes-different-files-if-app-is-debug-or-release-version/45014035#45014035

Comment: Do you mean: before class name like this: "@Keep
abstract public class BaseModel {" right ?

Comment: It works. Thanks, Frank.